# list.append() where am I wrong?

Tags: python

I have a string which is very long. I would like to split this string into substrings 16 characters long, skipping one character every time (e.g. substring1=first 16 elements of the string, substring2 from element 18 to element 34 and so on) and list them.

I wrote the following code:

```
string="abcd..."
list=[]
for j in range(0,int(len(string)/17)-1):
    list.append(string[int(j*17):int(j*17+16)])
```

But it returns:

```
list=[]
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7 or Python 3?

Comment: FYI `range` supports a `step` argument so that you can produce `[start, start+step, start+2*step...]`

Comment: what's length of string?

Comment: Also, your posted code works for me.

Comment: This code worked perfectly for me. I used `string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` and I named the `list` as `l` instead of `list` to avoid overwriting the built-in, but I didn't touch the actual algorithm.

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name; you are masking the built-in type. Your code actually works, albeit using a lot of redundant `int()` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> string="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Your original code, without masking the built-in (excludes the final full-length string and any partial string after it):

```
>>> l = []
>>> for j in range(0,int(len(string)/17)-1):
...     l.append(string[int(j*17):int(j*17+16)])
...
>>> l
['abcdefghijklmnop', 'rstuvwxyzabcdefg', 'ijklmnopqrstuvwx']
```

A cleaned version that includes all possible strings:

```
>>> for j in range(0,len(string),17):
...     l.append(string[j:j+16])
...
>>> l
['abcdefghijklmnop', 'rstuvwxyzabcdefg', 'ijklmnopqrstuvwx', 'zabcdefghijklmno', 'qrstuvwxyz']
```

How about we turn that last one into a comprehension? Everyone loves comprehensions.

```
>>> l = [string[j:j+16] for j in range(0,len(string),17)]
```

We can filter out strings that are too short if we want to:

```
>>> l = [string[j:j+16] for j in range(0,len(string),17) if len(string[j:j+16])>=16]
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work -- but only for strings longer than 16 characters.  You have

```
range(0,int(len(string)/17)-1)
```

but, for the string "abcd...", `int(len(string)/17)-1)` is -1.  Add some logic to catch the < 16 chars case and you're good:

```
...
for j in range(0, max(1, int(len(string)/17)-1)):
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

string="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
liszt=[]
leng=5
for j in range(0,len(string)/leng):
  ibeg=j*(leng+1)
  liszt.append(string[ibeg:ibeg+leng])
if ibeg+leng+1 < len(string):
  liszt.append(string[ibeg+leng:])
print liszt
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> s = ascii_lowercase * 2
>>> s
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> spl = [s[i:i+16] for i in range(0, len(s), 17)]
>>> spl
['abcdefghijklmnop', 'rstuvwxyzabcdefg', 'ijklmnopqrstuvwx', 'z']
```